# When returning a member variable, why do I get different results inside and outside a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, return

When I try and print a member variable inside a function, it gives me the desired result. However, if I return this member variable and then try to access it in main, it gives me a different result. Why is this the case?

Here is what my code looks like:

Node.h:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
 public:
    int v;
    Node * parent;
    Node(int I);
    Node(int I,Node * p);
    vector<Node*> myfun();
}
```

Node.cpp:

```
Node::Node(int I){
    v = I;
    parent = NULL;
}

Node::Node(int I,Node * p){
    v = I;
    parent = p;
}

vector<Node*> Node::myfun(){
    vector<Node*> myvec;

    Node next1(1,this);
    myvec.push_back(&next1);

    Node next2(2,this);
    myvec.push_back(&next2);

    cout << myvec[0]->v << endl; // prints out "1"
    cout << myvec[1]->v << endl; // prints out "2"

    return(myvec);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Node.h"

int main(){
    vector<Node*> myvec;
    Node init(0);
    myvec = init.myfun();

    cout << myvec[0]->v << endl; // prints out garbage
    cout << myvec[1]->v << endl; // prints out garbage

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your `Node::myfun()` your `next1` and `next2` variables are both destroyed (they cease to exist) at the end of the method. You're therefore returning pointers to object that no longer exist. Such pointers are known as **dangling pointers**, and dereferencing a dangling pointer is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: But I'm pushing those back on `myvec`, which gets returned. Does it matter that `next1` and `next2` are destroyed? How can I fix my problem?

Comment: @awilds You're pushing their addresses, which are stack addresses.  Use `new`.

Comment: Or make `myvec` a `vector<Node>`, or use `std::shared_ptr`. `new` isn't exactly considered cool anymore.

Comment: @Biffen Dems fightin' words.  `std::shared_ptr` has some thread barrier crap in it last I checked (someone asked a question about it on SO not long ago).